# get one of the field value checkbox with multiple value in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is the checkbox code that I have :

`echo "<input  type='checkbox' name='pilx[]' value='$dt_item[KodeCust];$dt_item[NoTransaksi];".round($saldoakhir).";' onclick='clickCh(this)' >";`

The values will look like this

```
P3004;KCP/3409;310000
P3009;KCP/3409;590000
P3001;KCP/3409;399000

var TOTAL = document.getElementById("TOTAL") 
function clickCh(caller)
{  
  if(caller.checked){
     add(caller)
  } else {
     subtract(caller)
  }
}
function add(caller)
{
   TOTALPIUTANG.value = TOTAL.value*1 + caller.value*1;
}
function subtract(caller)
{
 TOTALPIUTANG.value = TOTAL.value*1 - caller.value*1;
}
```

The script only works with one value.
Any suggestion how to sum only the third value (310000+590000+399000)?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function add(caller) {
    var elmarray = caller.value.split(';');
    TOTALPIUTANG.value = TOTAL.value * 1 + elmarray[elmarray.length - 1] * 1;
}

function subtract(caller) {
    var elmarray = caller.value.split(';');
    TOTALPIUTANG.value = TOTAL.value * 1 - elmarray[elmarray.length - 1] * 1;
}
```